# Tree identification

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees, flowers

I went to [Araku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araku_Valley) few days ago and saw this tree in a garden .
[image: flower]

[image: thalamus]

Here are the leaves
[image: leaves]

I know the pic of fruits is a bit hazy and out of focus,but it's the best I have.
[image: fruits]
These trees were in a cluster ,behind a patch of [Nerium shrubs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerium) beside the pavement of the garden.

Comment: Please provide as much detail as possible for the most accurate ID. If you have additional photos showing the leaves in detail, the bark, the general shape/size of the tree, etc. please include them. Please also comment on the relative sizes of the flowers/leaves/tree in your images and include any pertinent info about the ecology/environment of the tree (e.g., was it in a forested part of the garden, along a sidewalk, part of landscaping, etc. etc.) Thanks

Comment: Last picture is flower buds

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a flower of a tree in the *Syzygium* genus.

Because there are many species (1200+) -- many which are intentionally planted as ornamentals outside of their native range or have the propensity to become invasive -- I cannot confidently provide a more specific species given the garden location in which you found your specimen (and lack of further details).

I include, as an example, an image from the [University of Connecticut](http://florawww.eeb.uconn.edu/199800085.html) of *Syzygium jambos*, which is not native to India, but is known to [grow in nearby regions](http://florawww.eeb.uconn.edu/images/maps/tdwg/199800085.png).

[image]

Notice the similar floral architecture to your specimen: dominant [androecium](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/androecium) (literally hundreds of stamens), whitish color, 4-lobed [calyx](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calyx), prominent [hypanthium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypanthium), etc. Multiple flowers also similarly cluster at the end of branches as in your photo.

- Read more about *S. jambos*'s floral description  [here](https://hort.purdue.edu/newcrop/morton/rose_apple.html).

Sometimes-similar *Eugenia* cannot be totally ruled out based on your limited photos/details, of which [25 species](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342616971_The_genus_Eugenia_L_Myrtaceae_in_India) occur in India. However, *Syzygium* still seems much more likely.

Overall, I can update my answer with more details once you've updated your post.